# Need help with understanding exponential form.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm looking at this example in my book:
$$z = -1 - i$$
The book doesn't explain how it got to the exponential form, which is:
$$\sqrt2e^{-i3\pi/4}$$
I understand how $3\pi/4$ was found, but I don't understand where the $\sqrt2$ came from.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z = -1 - i$, what is its modulus $|z| = \sqrt{z \bar{z}}$?

Comment: Ah, that would be $\sqrt{(-1 - i)(-1 - i)} = \sqrt{2i}$.  Am I right, and do you drop the $i$?

EDIT: I missed the conjugate.  So, it would actually be $\sqrt{(-1 - i)(-1 + i)} = \sqrt{2}$.  I see the $i's$ cancel.  Thanks